# Why is $(x^2+1)$ an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In my algebra textbook I see the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle $ so that implies that $ \langle x^2+1 \rangle $ is a bilateral ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ but I don't see why.Can someone explain me why?

I see it satisfyes the condition:

- $\forall f,h\in \langle x^2+1 \rangle, f+h $ is in $  \langle x^2+1 \rangle $

But I don't think it satisfyes the condition:

- $\forall f \in Z[x]$ and $h \in <x^2+1>,f*h \in \langle x^2+1 \rangle $

For example let's take $f = 2x$ and $h \in <x^2+1>,h = x^2+1$ then $f*h = 2x^3+2x$ where * is the usual multiplication of polynomials , but that is not in the ideal generated by $x^2+1$ , right ? Am I wrong somewhere?

EDIT : $ \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle $ is the ideal generated by $x^2 +1$

Comment: How is the notation $(x^2+1)$ _defined_ for you?

Comment: $fh=(2x)(x^2+1)$. So $fh \in \langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: An how do you get $2x\cdot(x^2+1)$ to be $2x^3+2$ rather than $2x^3+2x$?

Comment: First thing, $Z[X]$ is commutative, so you don't need to mention *bilateral* ideals. Second, in a commutative ring $A$, if $a \in A$, then $(a)$ is defined as the set $aA = \{ax \mid x \in A \}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my bad, I edited now, I hope is all good.Sorry in my college that's how we denote Ideals , by the notation (..)

Comment: @EduardValentin: I'm still waiting to see what your **definition** of $(x^2+1)$ is. With all the definitions I can think of, it is _obvious by definition_ that the product of any $f$ with $x^2+1$ is in $(x^2+1)$. If you have a definition where this is _not_ the case, you need to reveal to us what it is.

Comment: To nicely format angle brackets, use `\langle \rangle` rather than `< >`. This gives $\langle x \rangle$ rather than $<x>$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's the Ideal generated by $x^2 + 1$

Comment: @EduardValentin: And **what is your definition** of "the ideal generated by ..."? I am not quibbling about of your notation; I'm asking what those words (or symbols, whatever you want) _mean_ to you. To me "the ideal generated by $a$" is _either_ the set of all products of $a$ with something, _or_ (equivalently) the smallest ideal of the ring that contains $a$, _or_ (equivalently) the intersection of all ideals in the ring that contain $a$. In _each_ of those cases it is _immediately clear_ that no matter what you multiply $a$ by, the result _will_ be in $\langle a \rangle$.

Comment: $ \langle x^2+1 \rangle = \{  f_1 * h_1 * f'_1+ .... + f_i*h_i * f'_i | f \in \mathbb{Z}[X] ,h \in \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \}$

Comment: @EduardValentin: That is a circular dedfinition -- it has $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ on the right-hand side too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ah you are right, looking at it I see I had the wrong idea about ideals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the notation $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ means "the smallest ideal containing $x^2 + 1$", it is, in fact, an *ideal*. Nothing more needs to be said.

---

One can characterize the ideal generated by a set of ring elements as the set of all linear combinations of the generators, where the coefficients of the linear combination are ring elements.

You never say anywhere why you think $fh$ is not in $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$. The only mistake I can imagine you making is forgetting that the coefficients can be arbitrary ring elements rather than merely integers.

But with questions like these, you really should do your best to explain why you think something isn't true, rather than just announcing it and expecting everyone else to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: I just tought that if we multiply an element of the ring with one of the ideal , it should be a multiple of the generator , but I had the definition of the ideal totaly wrong in my head .. sorry

Comment: @EduardValentin: Why do you think $2x^3+2x$ is not a multiple of $x^2+1$? You just _got it_ yourself by multiplying $x^2+1$ by something! It looks like you're misunderstanding what "a multiple" is.

Comment: I meant a power of the generator , like $(x^2+1)^k$